# Django shell runs in python 2.7.11 instead of 3.6.2

Tags: django, python-3.x, powershell

When i run "py manage.py shell" in powershell it runs the shell as expected however it runs it in python 2.7.11 while i need it to run with 3.6.2
Is there any way to get it to run in python 3.6 instead of 2.7?

Comment: What is `py`? Make sure it points to Python 3. Try using `python3 manage.py shell` instead.

Comment: What is py command here? I would presume its some-kind of alias pointing to Python rather than Python3 which would cause it to run Python 2.7.x. As suggested above by @kichik use Python3 or better use virtual environment rather than global Python install as using global install is going to cause issues sooner or later

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
py -3.6 manage.py shell
```